# Can't get the result of my field using for Loop

Tags: java

I have this method that returns an int :

```
public Integer getMyTest()
    {
         Integer test;
         for (int i = 0; i < this.id.getChoice().size(); i++)
         {
             if (this.id.getChoice().get(i).getCode().getId().equals(this.id.getId()))
             {
                 if(this.value.equals(this.id.getChoice().get(i).getCode().getCode())
                    && this.id.getChoice().get(i).getText().contains("Test1"))
                 {
                     Integer myresult = this.id.getTest().get(0);
                     test = myresult;
                     return test;
                 }
                 else if(this.value.equals(this.id.getChoice().get(i).getCode().getCode())
                      && this.id.getChoice().get(i).getText().contains("Test2"))
                 {
                     Integer myresult = this.id.getTest().get(1);
                     test = myresult;
                     return test;
                 }
                 else if(this.value.equals(this.id.getChoice().get(i).getCode().getCode())
                        && this.id.getChoice().get(i).getText().contains("Test3"))
                 {

                     Integer myresult = this.id.getTest().get(2);
                     test = myresult;
                     return test;
                 }
                 else if(this.value.equals(this.id.getChoice().get(i).getCode().getCode())
                         && this.id.getChoice().get(i).getText().contains("Test4"))
                 {
                     Integer myresult = this.id.getTest().get(3);
                     test = myresult;
                     return test;
                 }
                 else if(this.value.equals(this.id.getChoice().get(i).getCode().getCode())
                       && this.id.getChoice().get(i).getText().contains("Test5"))
                 {
                     Integer myresult = this.id.getTest().get(4);
                     test = myresult;
                     System.out.println("TEST 1 :" + test);
                     return test;
                 }
                 else if(this.value.equals(this.id.getChoice().get(i).getCode().getCode())
                         && this.id.getChoice().get(i).getText().contains("Test5"))
                 {
                     Integer myresult  = this.id.getTest().get(5);
                     test = myresult;
                     System.out.println("TEST 2 :" + test);
                     return test;
                 }
             }
             else return 0;
         }

       //here! is my problem .. 
         return test;

    }
```

I want to return the the test which is calculate into if blocs, each if has its own test. The problem is when I exit **if blocs and for bloc** it says that test `might not have been initialized` and does not save/get the test result (which its IF is true). When I initialized it to null it returns null value!

What should I do to fix this problem and get the test which is calculate into if blocs?

Thanks.

Comment: `test` is definitely not initialized after your `if` blocks. You return if you do set it. Change that last line (`return test;`) to `return 0;`

Comment: You need to set a last else in the 2nd block of ifs where you define a value. Or make sure the variable will be defined in any of the if blocks. Or initialize the test with a value.

Comment: The 2 bottom ifs have the same if statement. Maybe something wrong there.

Comment: if `this.id.getChoice().size(); ` is zero. the Loop will not executed. that sees the compiler.

Comment: If it is initialized and returned null value, that means you have a problem with your *for loop* or *if* blocks. Try to debug it by checking values of getChoice() arraylist contents each time you are in an if blocks or print its size to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code as :

```
Integer test =0; // at the time of initialization
```

and replace

```
else return 0;
}

//here! is my problem .. 
return test;
```

with just

```
else return test; // the last return within the scope of its declaration
```

Also, note that this is considering that you are returning test for all other conditions as you update the values.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is to initialize test by saying: `Integer test = 0;`
then you can always return test, even where you `return 0;`. This way your test is initialized before the loop starts.

The problem with your code was that when it should not pass for the first if, test is never initialized, but you return test after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your variable test is useless because each time you assign a value to it, there is a return statement right after. So I would suggest you remove the variable test and all its assignments, and just return myresult (or whatever). For the last test (the one that returns the uninitialized test), return whatever value you should return when none of the other conditions have been met. You can also replace it with a throw statement if it's an error case.